# Select where field1 or field2 or field3 is equal to a phone number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking at a table with phone1, phone2 and mobile. However the phone strings are not formatted properly.

The phone numbers are basically free text like this:

```
row1: phone1:19123123123
row2: mobile:+1 912 123 123
row3: phone2:1 912 123 123
row4: mobile:(+1) 912 123 123
row5: phone2:(+1)912-123-123
```

Is it possible to write a SQL query to find if one of the fields phone1, phone2 or mobile is +19123123123 but it needs to be able to match any one of those free text examples? Thanks

So in the above example, it should return all 5 records be those free text match that phone number and is in one of the 3 fields.

Comment: I see that it's possible to [use regex in sql statements](https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/how-regex-works-in-sql/). Maybe it could help you. BTW, add a tag to tell us what your database is : Oracle, Postgresql, MySQL... ?

Comment: [Google](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) created a library to validate phonenumbers. If you have to do this yourself its going to be a lot of work...

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and pattern matching functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Strip away all non-digit characters from the string and then compare

Comment: tagged dbms and updated the example

Comment: Also mention your MySQL version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the only numbers and `+` in the column are in the phone number, you can use:

```
where regexp_replace(col, '[^+0-9]', '') = '+19123123123'
```

This removes everything that is not a `+` or digit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Regex to identify phone number pattern or you can just remove all parenthesis and spaces from the both side of the where clause and then compare.

```
     SELECT * FROM T 
    WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone1, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '+19123123123'
        OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone1, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '19123123123'
        OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone2, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '+19123123123'
        OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone2, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '19123123123'
        OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(mobile, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '+19123123123'
        OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(mobile, '(',''),')',''),' ','') = '19123123123'
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Juergen, you can strip all non numeric character and compare. If you are on MySQL 8.0+, you can use below code

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ':', -1),'[^0-9]+',"")
```

*Assumption : Column value is always being separated by **colon(:)** after mobile/phone/sometext. Here it will take the second part of your string after colon and then strip the non numeric characters*